# Connection refused on debugging

Tags: arm, linux, lpcxpresso

I'm trying to debug my dev board here, using LPCXpresso v7.1.1 [Build 125] [2014-04-01] , Manjaro linux (Arch based), and a J-link programmer. Every time I tried to debug my program, I got an error: connection refused. I've installed the 32 bit libs already.

Finally I was able to install the appropriate packages for the J-link and GDB. Now xpresso launches the debug session, but it looks like nothing happens. If I watch the GDB server in the terminal, while I launch xpresso's debug, I get this:

> Resetting target Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00000000
>
> Downloading 2968 bytes @ address 0x00001000
>
> Downloading 20 bytes @ address 0x00001B98
>
> Writing register (R8 = 0x00000301) WARNING: Unsupported register (1)
>
> Reading register (PRIMASK = 0x00000000) GDB closed TCP/IP connection

I'm using an LPC1769.

Comment: 'Connection refused' has exactly one meaning. There is nothing listening at the IP:port you specified. Many years ago it could also indicate a firewall rule violation, but as that constitutes an information leak it has been abandoned in favor of no response at all, which would produce a 'connect timeout'.

Comment: Finally I could install the appropiate packages for the Jlink, and gdb. Now, I the xpresso launch the debug session, but it looks like nothing happens. If I watch the gdb server in the terminal, while I launch xpresso's debug, I got this:

Resetting target
Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 2968 bytes @ address 0x00001000
Downloading 20 bytes @ address 0x00001B98
Writing register (R8 = 0x00000301)
WARNING: Unsupported register (1)
Reading register (PRIMASK = 0x00000000)
GDB closed TCP/IP connection

I use LPC1769